# Where can I find javafx for openjdk 191 that works on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, openjfx

I am trying to build/pack an jre based on openjdk 191.

I downloaded an jfx overlay from: https://chriswhocodes.com/. But with this javafx only works on Windows 10.

And according to this: https://github.com/mediathekview/MediathekView/issues/345 javafx and openjdk will never work on Windows 7.

Is there any way I can make javafx and openjdk work on Windows 7?

The "official" download page https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Download redirects me to https://openjfx.io/m which deals exclusively with java 11 and openjfx 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a now quite a few builds available for openjdk which contain javafx for windows.

1. [Microsoft Azul](https://www.azul.com/zulu-gets-graphical-with-openjfx)
2. [Amazon Coretto](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/windows-7-install.html)

AdoptOpenjdk seems to have plans for a javafx integration, but it is not available, yet.